# Combining XML files and "title" each section

Tags: xml, xslt, powershell

I need to combine several xml files and tell the xml which section belongs to each file. Below are the two examples of such files.

D:\pathtoxml\1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="name" type="theres stuff here" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="valueOfKey1" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

D:\pathtoxml\2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="valueofkey1" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring1" connectionString="connectionstringstuff" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The end file needs to look like this

```
<WebConfigs>
  <path = 'D:\pathtoxml\1.xml'>
    <!-- 
      Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
      web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
      the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
      A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
      machine.config.comments usually located in 
      \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
    -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="name" type="theres stuff here" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="key1" value="valueOfKey1" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
  </path>
  <path = 'D:\pathtoxml\2.xml'>
    <!-- 
      Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
      web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
      the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
      A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
      machine.config.comments usually located in 
      \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
    -->
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="key1" value="valueofkey1" />
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connectionstring1" connectionString="connectionstringstuff" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
  </path>
</WebConfigs>
```

My current code looks like this however I get all sorts of XML errors

```
$path1 = 'D:\pathtoxml\1.xml'
$path2 = 'D:\pathtoxml\2.xml'
$exportPath = 'D:\exportPath\combined.xml'

$finalXml = "<path = '" + $path1 + "'>"
[xml]$xml = get-content $path1
$finalXml += $xml.InnerXml
$finalXml += "</path>"
$finalXml += "<path = '" + $path1 + "'>"
[xml]$xml = get-content $path2
$finalXml += $xml.InnerXml
$finalXml += "</path>"
([xml]$finalXml).Save($exportPath)
```

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397181/combining-xml-files) however it doesn't address adding in a way to tell in the combined file where each files source was.

Comment: Why don't you let us know what the first of the "all sorts of XML errors" is, and we can proceed to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already finding out, Powershell's XML is powerful but touchy.  I honestly don't fully understand it at this point, but this operation is pretty straightforward.  I have found that the `XmlElement` object type is easiest for me to work with when dealing with child nodes and the final product as an `XmlDocument` object. (The `<variable>.<node>` constructs imply `XmlElement`)

```
$PathList = "C:\Test\1.xml","C:\Test\2.xml"
$exportPath = 'C:\Test\combined.xml'

#Cheating a bit, but we don't need much
$finalXml = [xml]("<xml></xml>")

ForEach($Path in $PathList){
    $CurrentXml = [xml](Get-Content $Path)
    $CurrentXml.configuration.SetAttribute("path",$Path)

    <#
      Powershell's XML is touchy.
      Imports the original document into $finalXml's namespace, 
      then appends it to the first level inside $finalXml's document node.
    #>
    $importedNode = $finalXml.ImportNode($CurrentXml.DocumentElement, $true)
    $finalXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($importedNode) 
}

$finalXml.Save($exportPath)
```

This doesn't follow your output *exactly*, but the `<webconfigs>` and `<path>` nodes are probably superfluous if that's all your output needs to save.  It should look like this:

```
<xml>
    <configuration path="D:\pathtoxml\1.xml">
        ...
    </configuration>
    <configuration path="D:\pathtoxml\2.xml">
        ...
    </configuration>
</xml>
```

References:

[`XmlElement` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`XmlDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)